# Mask folder name and show only subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this structure:

```
http://mywebsite.com/folder/myapp1
http://mywebsite.com/folder/myapp2
http://mywebsite.com/folder/myapp3
```

How can I do to hide "folder" in the URL using .htaccess?

That is, if I enter 
    http://mywebsite.com/myapp1

I want it to display the contents of 
    http://mywebsite.com/folder/myapp1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This should work for you inyour .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) folder/$1 [L]
```